# Eclipse Project Facet: Java 1.8 not visible on imported Git project (Eclipse Neon 3, 4.6.3)

Tags: eclipse

I am using **Eclipse Neon 3 (4.6.3)**, and all my projects have the Java 1.8 Project Facet:

[image]

I have a new project. On this new one, I cloned a GitHub Repository and then did an Import to create a Web Project from the cloned Git code.

On this new imported project, the Java 1.8 facet is missing.

[image]

I added JDK 1.8 to my Build Path as the JRE library:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, my Runtime for Tomcat 8.5 was using a Java 1.7 JRE.

The solution was as described here: Create a new Project Facet Runtime for Tomcat and specify JRE 1.8:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29120634/1005607